# Essential supremum product inequality.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f,g\in\mathcal{L}_{\infty}(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ where $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space.

I am trying to show that $||fg||_{\infty} \leq ||f||_{\infty}||g||_{\infty}$.

I know that $|f(x)|\leq ||f||_\infty$ $\mu$-almost everywhere but I'm not even sure if this is useful since I'm not sure if we can say that $|f(x)||g(x)|\leq||f||_{\infty}||g||_{\infty}$ almost everywhere.

How should I be approaching this?

Comment: Let $A=(|f(x)|> ||f||_{\infty}$, $B=(|g(x)|>||g||_{\infty})$. What can you say about $\mu(A\cup B)$?

Answer (score 5):

Let 
$$
A := \{x\in X:\ |f(x)| \leq \|f\|_\infty\},
\qquad
B := \{x\in X:\ |g(x)| \leq \|g\|_\infty\}.
$$
Since $\mu(X\setminus A) = \mu(X\setminus B) = 0$, you have that $\mu(X\setminus (A\cup B)) = 0$.
Hence
$$
|f(x) g(x)| \leq \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_\infty
\qquad \forall x\in A\cup B,
$$
i.e. $\mu$-a.e.

By definition, this fact implies that $\|fg\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A_f = \{x\in X : |f(x)|>\|f\|_\infty\}$. We can see that $\mu (A_f) = 0$, so if $f$ and $g$ are measurable then $\mu(A_f\cup A_g) = 0$. For $x\notin A_f\cup A_g$ we have $|f(x)g(x)| \le \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_\infty$. That is, $|f(x)g(x)| \le \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_\infty$ almost everywhere.